# Why is Firestore returning inconsistent results when queried inside Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My goal is to create an idempotent cloud function that updates a counter of certain documents.

Instead of increasing or decreasing a counter, I'm querying for the documents and updating the counter with the total number of results.

```
const db = admin.firestore();

export const unprocessedReceiptsCount = 
functions.firestore.document('Purchases/{purchaseId}')
.onWrite(async (snapshot, context) => {

    const unprocessedRef = db.collection('Purchases').where('hasBeenProcessed', '==', false);
    const unprocessedSnap = await unprocessedRef.get();
    const count = unprocessedSnap.docs.length;
    console.log(count);
    return count;

});
```

As I update the hasBeenProcessed field in any document, it should log a consistent number. However, I'm getting results all over the board: 2, 63, 8, 44. Each time the function runs, it shows what seems to be a random number.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Finally, this is an answer:

The Google folks said this:

The error is caused by this issue https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/895 . Our engineers advised to removed the node_modules and try installing again since grpc-js 0.4.1 is unpublished now.

Their solution didn't work for me, but this did:

```
npm uninstall @grpc/grpc-js
npm install @grpc/grpc-js@0.4.0
```

That also fixes the problem in Cloud Functions.

---- original comment ---

I'm getting the same problem. This was working fine last week, now even a simple get() with no limits returns a random number of results.

The following code demonstrates the problem with the admin SDK. I have filed a bug report with Google.

```
var count = 10
getAgain()
function getAgain() {
  admin.firestore().collection('activity').get().then((qs) => {
    console.log("activities: got " + qs.docs.length)
    count--
    if (count) getAgain()
  })
}

CONSOLE LOG:
activities: got 24
activities: got 6
activities: got 6
activities: got 2
activities: got 11
activities: got 6
activities: got 2
activities: got 12
activities: got 13
activities: got 14
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, welcome to stack overflow. Answers are not comments, you may wish to delete this as it will be downvoted fairly quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Thomas. As Tim suggested, please delete this answer and add it as a comment to the main question, where it is more appropriate. Also, +1 the main question so we can get visibility and possibly a solution. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on the original question.